# InfluxDB - ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE - Used to come up in browser, now doesn't

Tags: docker, connection, localhost, influxdb

Running influxdb from a Docker container.

The YML includes Telegraf and Grafana, too.

I should point out that Grafana also is not loading in my browser.

When I run `netstat -n -q`, and I look for "8086", I find these entries:

- `0.0.0.0:8086`
- `[::]:8086`
- `[::1]:8086`

But I don't see 127.0.0.1:8086 as I would expect.

Here is the YAML.

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
influxdb:
  image: influxdb:latest
  container_name: influxdb
  ports:
    - "8083:8083"
    - "8086:8086"
    - "8090:8090"
  env_file:
    - 'env.influxdb'
  volumes:
    # Data persistency
    # sudo mkdir -p /srv/docker/influxdb/data
    - /srv/docker/influxdb/data:/var/lib/influxdb2

telegraf:
  image: telegraf:latest
  container_name: telegraf
  links:
    - influxdb
  volumes:
    - ./telegraf.conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf:ro

grafana:
  image: grafana/grafana:latest
  container_name: grafana
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  env_file:
    - 'env.grafana'
  user: "0"
  links:
    - influxdb
  volumes:
    # Data persistency
    # sudo mkdir -p /srv/docker/grafana/data; chown 472:472 /srv/docker/grafana/data
    # - /srv/docker/grafana/data:/var/lib/grafana
    - grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana
```

When I first ran this, I used:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Until today, it was running fine on http://localhost:8086.

Today, running from Docker as last time, when I go to the above URL, I get:
[image]

Here is log output in Docker Desktop:

```
ts=2021-05-30T08:24:46.820359Z lvl=info msg="Terminating precreation service" log_id=0UR5So2l000 service=shard-precreation

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:46.820369Z lvl=info msg=Stopping log_id=0UR5So2l000 service=scraper

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:46.820362Z lvl=info msg=Stopping log_id=0UR5So2l000 service=telemetry interval=8h

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:46.820545Z lvl=info msg=Stopping log_id=0UR5So2l000 service=tcp-listener

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:47.320800Z lvl=info msg=Stopping log_id=0UR5So2l000 service=task

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:47.321127Z lvl=info msg=Stopping log_id=0UR5So2l000 service=nats

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:47.321618Z lvl=info msg=Stopping log_id=0UR5So2l000 service=bolt

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:47.321727Z lvl=info msg=Stopping log_id=0UR5So2l000 service=query

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:47.322865Z lvl=info msg=Stopping log_id=0UR5So2l000 service=storage-engine

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:47.322923Z lvl=info msg="Closing retention policy enforcement service" log_id=0UR5So2l000 service=retention

2021-05-30T08:24:48.156974500Z info found existing boltdb file, skipping setup wrapper {"system": "docker", "bolt_path": "/var/lib/influxdb2/influxd.bolt"}

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.290693Z lvl=info msg="Welcome to InfluxDB" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 version=2.0.6 commit=4db98b4c9a build_date=2021-04-29T16:48:12Z

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.295514Z lvl=info msg="Resources opened" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=bolt path=/var/lib/influxdb2/influxd.bolt

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.310335Z lvl=info msg="Checking InfluxDB metadata for prior version." log_id=0UR5r_zW000 bolt_path=/var/lib/influxdb2/influxd.bolt

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.310424Z lvl=info msg="Using data dir" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine service=store path=/var/lib/influxdb2/engine/data

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.310463Z lvl=info msg="Compaction settings" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine service=store max_concurrent_compactions=4 throughput_bytes_per_second=50331648 throughput_bytes_per_second_burst=50331648

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.310473Z lvl=info msg="Open store (start)" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open op_event=start

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.312517Z lvl=info msg="Skipping database dir" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open name=20210513T163414Z.bolt reason="not a directory"

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.312542Z lvl=info msg="Skipping database dir" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open name=20210513T163414Z.manifest reason="not a directory"

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.312547Z lvl=info msg="Skipping database dir" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open name=20210513T163414Z.s1.tar.gz reason="not a directory"

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.312550Z lvl=info msg="Skipping database dir" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open name=20210513T163414Z.s2.tar.gz reason="not a directory"

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.321805Z lvl=info msg="index opened with 8 partitions" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine index=tsi

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.322485Z lvl=info msg="index opened with 8 partitions" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine index=tsi

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.322798Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb2/engine/data/0955e2d35090f6ad/autogen/3/000000006-000000002.tsm id=0 duration=0.152ms

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.322945Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open index_version=tsi1 path=/var/lib/influxdb2/engine/data/0955e2d35090f6ad/autogen/3 duration=10.298ms

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.323162Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb2/engine/data/0955e2d35090f6ad/autogen/2/000000011-000000002.tsm id=0 duration=0.091ms

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.323284Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open index_version=tsi1 path=/var/lib/influxdb2/engine/data/0955e2d35090f6ad/autogen/2 duration=10.738ms

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.323515Z lvl=info msg="index opened with 8 partitions" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine index=tsi

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.324371Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb2/engine/data/0955e2d35090f6ad/autogen/1/000000005-000000002.tsm id=0 duration=0.469ms

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.324496Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open index_version=tsi1 path=/var/lib/influxdb2/engine/data/0955e2d35090f6ad/autogen/1 duration=11.925ms

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.325086Z lvl=info msg="index opened with 8 partitions" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine index=tsi

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.325935Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb2/engine/data/0955e2d35090f6ad/autogen/5/000000014-000000001.tsm id=2 duration=0.081ms

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.326047Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb2/engine/data/0955e2d35090f6ad/autogen/5/000000012-000000001.tsm id=1 duration=0.058ms

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.326145Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb2/engine/data/0955e2d35090f6ad/autogen/5/000000011-000000002.tsm id=0 duration=0.223ms

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.326235Z lvl=info msg="Reading file" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=cacheloader path=/var/lib/influxdb2/engine/wal/0955e2d35090f6ad/autogen/5/_00027.wal size=1081786

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.391805Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open index_version=tsi1 path=/var/lib/influxdb2/engine/data/0955e2d35090f6ad/autogen/5 duration=79.067ms

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.392033Z lvl=info msg="Open store (end)" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open op_event=end op_elapsed=81.559ms

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.392062Z lvl=info msg="Starting retention policy enforcement service" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=retention check_interval=30m

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.392070Z lvl=info msg="Starting precreation service" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=shard-precreation check_interval=10m advance_period=30m

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.392109Z lvl=info msg="Starting query controller" log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=storage-reads concurrency_quota=1024 initial_memory_bytes_quota_per_query=9223372036854775807 memory_bytes_quota_per_query=9223372036854775807 max_memory_bytes=0 queue_size=1024

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.393194Z lvl=info msg="Configuring InfluxQL statement executor (zeros indicate unlimited)." log_id=0UR5r_zW000 max_select_point=0 max_select_series=0 max_select_buckets=0

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.703897Z lvl=info msg=Listening log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=tcp-listener transport=http addr=:8086 port=8086

ts=2021-05-30T08:24:55.704009Z lvl=info msg=Starting log_id=0UR5r_zW000 service=telemetry interval=8h
```

I do not see errors in this output.  Is there something I am missing?

Restarting the container did not help.

Seeking trouble-shooting ideas & possible causes.

Comment: Can you put the command you used to execute the docker container?

Comment: @ErangaHeshan - added to original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is a little embarrassing...  I restarted Docker Desktop.

Successfully logged into InfluxDB.  Dashboards appear.